# Remove NSManagedObject within commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm still a newbie in IOS development. I need to remove an object from my `ViewController` but XCode say that fetchedResultsController is unknown:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CoreData/CoreData.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        // two following lines probably are erroneous 
        NSManagedObject *entityToDelete =
        [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [mangedObjectContext deleteObject:entityToDelete];


        // Remove the row from data model
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [device valueForKey:@"name"], [device valueForKey:@"version"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [device valueForKey:@"company"];

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `self.devices` as your data model, not a fetchedResultsController.  If so, you should get a reference to the object to delete from that array:

```
    NSManagedObject *entityToDelete =
    [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [mangedObjectContext deleteObject:entityToDelete];
```

Comment: I changed the code. Now it says "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex'"

Comment: Ok - do you actually have a fetchedResultsController?

Comment: No, I haven't.          .

Comment: Can you show some more code eg your cellForRowAtIndexPath, and viewDidLoad?

Comment: viewDidLoad has only `[super viewDidLoad];`. Added **viewDidAppear** and **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the question:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
    // Delete object from database
    [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    // Remove the row from data model
    [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```